# VsCode Intellisense force to show all properties and methods

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ide

Is it possible (via settings or extensions) to show all methods and properties regardless context, like in WebStorm?
If I create an empty JS file, and type `"document.quer..."`, VS-Code's suggestion-widget, shows me querySelector, as well as other methods. But in my real project, if I type "root.quer...", there are no suggestions, and i must type it by hand.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: The widget that is responsible for displaying suggestions is Intellisense, and it is very good at what it does. I have experienced issues similar to the issue that you are experiencing now, and I can say this much: _If the property/method exists in in JS, a 3rd party module,  or if its a property/method that you wrote, intellisense will suggest it if it is there. Most likely, in my own experience, I have found that if intellisense isn't suggesting it, there's s 99.99% chance that your doing something wrong. Especially if intellisense finds it in other files, but not in your project.

Comment: Extension URL: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shannonliang.js-intellisense

This extension is based on https://ternjs.net/ and closest thing to Webstorm "autocomplete/autosuggest" module.

But, so far no extension that I can found like "autocompleting" in Webstorm. VS Code is an editor, so intellisense only suggests if you have used an attribute/method/property or have in your files. Cannot list whole methods and properties.

Comment: @JΛYDΞV is wrong. a very common scenario is when you do dependency injection, and intellisense has no way to know the type of that received object, unless you're using typescript.

Comment: if you haven't type annotated the return type of getDOMelement, and it can't be statically inferred what the return type is, then the return type will have type `any`. for a definitive answer to be given here,  we'd need a [mre].